# "ApplicationVerificationFailed" when trying to deploy from Flash Builder

Tags: ios, deployment, flash-builder

I'm getting this error, things already checked:

- the p12 is ok
- the provisioning is ok
- the appId matches

What else should I need to verify to get rid of this problem?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after searching all over the web I found the solution, happens that I had special characters in a couple of images, one of those had a í. Replaced that with an i, and problem solved.

(thanks adobe for detailing the error so nicely)